# What is wrong with my code? I keep getting the error "No implicit conversion from string to array (TypeError)"

Tags: ruby

The part that seems to be the problem is the first part of the `if` statement as the `else` section is working:

```
def self.abbreviate(string)
  if string.match("-")
    array = string.split("-")
    array.each do |word|
      if word.length > 3
          word.gsub!(/\w+/, "#{word[0]}#{word.length - 2}#{word[word.length - 1]}")
      end
    end
  else
    string.gsub!(/\w+/, "#{string[0]}#{string.length - 2}#{string[string.length - 1]}")
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do is to abbreviate words like so `"banana" => "b4a"`, `"hackers" => "h5s"`. This has to also work for hyphenated words like `"double-barrel" => "d4e-b4l"`

Comment: Can you provide an example where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably is in caller code, provided function returns string for words without `-` and an array for ones that have it:

```
abbreviate 'abc' => "a1c"
abbreviate 'abc-abc' => ["abc", "abc"]
```

but for what you're trying to do, the following seems more appropriate:

```
def self.abbreviate(string)
  string.split("-").map{|s|
    s.length > 2 ? "#{s[0]}#{s.size-2}#{s[-1]}" : s
  }.join('-')
end
```

it produces `abbreviate "abcd-abcd" => "a2d-a2d"`